# Skinning and caching user preferences

Tags: iphone, ios, skin

I have an application which allows customizing attributes such as background color, buttons, text (ie, titles), etc. In its current incarnation, `viewDidLoad` set the appropriate property on a UI widget by calling into a `LookAndFeel` class. `LookAndFeel` reads the user preferences.

Should each view perform a call into `LookAndFeel`, or should the Application fetch an attribute once and use the fetched value in all views? Is it OK to call `getTitleColor` once, hold it in the app delegate, and use it in every view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how expensive your `getTitleColor` method is. If it's expensive, it should definitely be cached.

(Note: reading from a file or from `NSUserDefaults` could be considered expensive)